# Do mysql update queries benefit from an index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which I do mainly updates and I'm wondering if update queries would benefit from having an index on the where column and the updated column or an index on just where column?

Comment: An index on the column in `WHERE` would (probably) help. Probably means it would help if it would help the equivalent `SELECT`. If, for example you have a `WHERE id > 3` condition and almost all ids are >3, then the index would not be used.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question, an index on `(wherecolumn, updatedcolumn)` might help too. But I think only because MySQL checks and does not do an update in the updated value is same with existing value of the column. So, `UPDATE t SET a=7 WHERE grp=47` might bennefit form a `(grp,a)` index if there are many rows with `grp=47` and `a` already equal to `7`.

Comment: What storage engine are you using, what is the structure of the table, and what is the update query?  These could all make a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just on the where column. An index on the update column will actually slow down your query because the index has to be updated along with the data. An index on the where column will speed up updates, and selects, but slow down some insertions.

Indices also cause overhead when you delete rows. In general they are a good thing though on columns you are using `WHERE` on a lot, and they are basically necessary on columns you do joins on, or `ORDER BY`

Comment: Well updating an index is done entirely in memory which is pretty fast. The update query is one which simply increments a column. I'm wondering if adding the second column to the index will spare an extra read to find the original value.

Comment: That's a good question. I'm think the MySQL optimizer would take advantage of the index, but it's hard to say. You could always turn on profiling and try out both queries and see if you notice anything.

Answer (score 17):

Not a straight forward answer for this one. So here goes.

```
UPDATE table SET ColumnA = 'something'
```

if an index exists on ColumnA then you will have a slight performance hit as there will be two write operations for each row. First the data in the table and then the write for the index update.
You can even have several indexes that each have ColumnA as part of the index which mean you will have several writes in addition to the table row. You can see how having more than a few indexes can start to really slow your updates down.
But if ColumnA is not indexed at all then it will be a single write for each row only.

```
UPDATE table SET ColumnA = 'something' WHERE ColumnB = 'something else'
```

For this query if an index exists on ColumnB and not on ColumnA, it will be very fast to locate the record (called a seek) and a single write to update, and as the index doesn't care about columnA, it wont need updating.
But if you index ColumnA and not ColumnB, You will read every row in the table first (called a scan and normally a bad thing) which while a read is faster than a write it is still very slow, then it will write to the table and then another write for the index. Basically the slowest way of doing things.

```
DELETE table WHERE ColumnB = 'somethingelse'
```

Now if you have an index on any column in this table two writes, delete from table and a update/delete of the record in the index.
 Again if ColumnB is not indexed, you will scan the table then delete the row(s) from the table and update indexes if any.

```
INSERT INTO table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ('something','something else')
```

If no indexes exist, a single write to the table and it's done.
Again, if indexes do exist, then an extra write for each one.

I haven't mentioned the primary key unique constraints, because you really cant get around them when you need a primary key, but every record must be checked to see if something already exists with that key before insert. Which will be a fast primary key index seek, but nevertheless, its another step in the process. The less steps the faster it will be.

Now back to yours, Basically, if you need to update a specific record, an index will help you locate that record faster than scanning the entire table. The the time saved to locate the record will be much more then the time lost updating the indexes. If you are only inserting and never reading, then indexes will slow you down. It becomes a balance thing. If you need to read specific records, then an index will help immensely. But the more indexes, the slower the writes get.

Comment: To which storage engine are you referring in your answer?

Answer (score 14):

Most people here don't know how indexes work in MySQL.

It depends on with **storage engine** you are using. InnoDB uses indexes completely different from MyISAM. This is because MySQL implements indexes on the **storage engine level** not the MySQL server level.

I'm afraid most people here are giving you answers based on other databases in which indexes **work differently** from MySQL.

**InnoDB**

In the case of `InnoDB`. This is because whenever a row is updated in `InnoDB`, the index has to be updated as well, as `InnoDB's` indexes have to be sequential, so it has to find out which page node of the index it is supposed to be in and inserted there. At times that particular page maybe full, so it has to **split the page**, wasting both space and increasing the time. This happens no matter which column you index because `InnoDB` uses clustered indexes, where the index stores the data of the entire row.

**MyISAM**

In the case of MyISAM, it does not have this problem. `MyISAM` actually uses only 1 column index, even though you can set multiple uniques on more than 1 column. Also `MyISAM's` index is not stored sequentially so updates are very quick. Likewise inserts are quick as well, as `MyISAM` just inserts it at the end of the row.

**Conclusion**

So in regard to your question, you should consider your schema design instead of worrying about whether the query would use the indexes. If you are updating mostly on a table, I suggest you not use `InnoDB` unless if you need row-level locking, high concurrency, and transactions. Otherwise `MyISAM` would be much better for update tasks. And no if you are using `InnoDB` indexes do not really help with updating, especially if the table is very large.

Comment: Without the use of transactions, how would you handle data corruption in MyISAM tables, if, for example, the server crashes during an update? This may be important for a table where updates are the primary action.

Comment: you can use `CHECK TABLE tablename` and `REPAIR TABLE tablename` or `myisamchk`. Usually this isn't the problem other than the time lost after a crash. On the contrary, InnoDB indexes are easily fragmented and it cannot be fixed using `ALTER TABLE innodbtable ENGINE=InnoDB` like other storage engines.


So it really depends on your situation.

Comment: If an update is in progress when a crash occurs, is it not true that data integrity can be compromised with MyISAM tables - depending on the update being performed, it may be very difficult to tell which records have been updated, and which have not? As for index fragmentation, the [docs state](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html) that it *can* be fixed with `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB`.  Am I missing something? Anyway, I'm heading off-topic here, and I agree that it depends on the situation.  But data integrity is an important consideration.

Comment: Yes, that is if he requires transactions, then by all means use it, but we don't know in what context he will be using the database. And yes you are correct, `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB` does work with defragmenting indexes by building the table again, I mixed that up with `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and dumping and reloading data for defragmenting indexes, which doesn't work with InnoDB.

Comment: I add my experience: I have to update multiple columns on a MyIsam table of 1 million rows, the WHERE part contains 3 column. After many experiments I found the best combination is to drop  all indexes on the table, add a tmp index only on the smallest column in WHERE part. Here an example of the update query:  UPDATE radio16 SET grp_flg = "S", ind = 570, adu = 570, uom = 470, don = 670, res = 670, m34 = 360 WHERE cod_test = 958010 AND dow = 6 AND qtd = 715;