# How inefficient is updating a column that is used in an index for the update

Tags: mysql, sql

We are considering doing a SQL query of the following:

```
UPDATE tableA SET columnA = columnB WHERE columnA = 0 LIMIT 1000
```

tableA has 1 billion rows and an index on columnA.  columnB is a highly selective data.

1) How bad will the performance of this be?  Will the fact that it is querying on the index that is being updated cause some sort of blocking on the index?  Or will the query complete first before doing the update?

2) Since this table has a billion rows, and we limit this to 1000 rows at a time, there will be many iterations of this query.  columnA is 0 initially, I'm certain that for the beginning part, it will be doing table scans.  But as the update progresses, and as columnA gets populated with the more selective columnB data, will the index help the query, or is it better to just drop the index and let it do table scans?

Comment: I hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769941/do-mysql-update-queries-benefit-from-an-index (for me is very similar)

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is almost meaningless. That said, this could just about be the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming InnoDB, the rows being updated will get exclusive (write) locks. This means that other `SELECT` queries can still read the records, but any query on the records that requires an exclusive lock (update query) will block until the locks are released (the transaction/query finishes).

In addition, any `SELECT` queries will see the old values until the query (transaction) is finished.

You are probably right about the usage of the index for selection. If you have a newer MySQL version, you should be able to do an `EXPLAIN` on the update query to see if it will be using the index. The `LIMIT` clause isn't usually considered in the query optimization, so not until the number of records that have 0 reduces significantly, will the index be used to satisfy the search.

However, since you know more about the query than MySQL does and know about the limited number of look ups that are actually required (the `LIMIT` clause), you can force the index in an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tableA FORCE INDEX (idx_columnA)
SET columnA = columnB WHERE columnA = 0 LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thank you.  How much of a performance impact will there be since it is using the index to query, but then the index has to be updated since the value is being changed in the UPDATE?  Is the hit to update the index worth the use of the index, which probably won't be very selective in the first place?

Comment: If you're adding the index just to speed the update, you're probably wasting your time. Adding the index will lock the whole table while it is being updated. Again, `SELECTS` will still work, but any `UPDATE` will block. If you're willing to do that, you might as well just update all the values at once. That brings us back to, what is your main concern? If you already have the index, my guess is it would be more advantageous to use it.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if dropping the index would result in a faster processing than having the index.  Dropping the index would mean that the update to the table would be faster, but the querying for the data would be slower.  So I'm trying to figure out if dropping the index is worth it or not.

Comment: In MySQL 5.5+, [dropping the index is trivial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html). Still, my guess is, using the index will complete the queries faster (if you force the index). Secondary index updates are very fast. You're comparing a known relatively small value (1 billion index updates), to scanning 1000 + 2000 + 3000 + 4000 + 5000 ... (continue the sequence until you have 1 million values) rows of table scanning. I'm also assuming your index fits in memory.