# Join and update take too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `FACT_SALE` and `DIM_PRODUCT` which both have the product name as common and I wanted to set the `DIM_PRODUCT`'s ID as a **foreign key**. `DIM_PRODUCT` is created with the distinct name values of the `FACT_SALE` table.

```
UPDATE FACT_SALE FS
JOIN DIM_PRODUCT DP ON FS.PRODUCT_NAME = DP.NAME
SET FS.PRODUCT_KEY = DP.ID
```

This query I wrote runs forever and no changes are reflected in the DB too. There is only one hundred thousand records (100 000) in the `FACT_SALE table`. But if I run a select query with Joining two table it runs lightning fast.

Can I know what is the root cause for this issue ?

Comment: Your join condition is on text field, and I suspecting that this field is not indexed, adding index to the field name might make way more fast, so just a test backup you database then add index to the fields FS.PRODUCT_NAME and DP.NAME then test your update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this query:

```
UPDATE FACT_SALE FS JOIN
       DIM_PRODUCT DP
       ON FS.PRODUCT_NAME = DP.NAME
SET FS.PRODUCT_KEY = DP.ID ;
```

You want an index on `DIM_PRODUCT(NAME, ID)`:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_DIM_PRODUCT_NAME_ID ON DIM_PRODUCT(NAME, ID);
```

Comment: @Ali I also enjoy Gordon's work...always a good time on Stack Overflow ^ ^

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. Would be great if I could get a resource page to know why this huge difference (like 20- 30x) in select join and update join. :) . Is update executed in a much more complex manner ?

Comment: @NirojanSelvanathan . . . Probably the only difference is that you are looking at the first row returned for the `SELECT`, but the `UPDATE` needs to process all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on either of the join columns `FACT_SALE.PRODUCT_NAME` or `DIM_PRODUCT.NAME`?  If you have indices on either of these columns could slow down the update because the index would have to be updated along with the data.

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769941/do-mysql-update-queries-benefit-from-an-index) an index would only benefit columns in the `WHERE` clause.  But since you don't have a `WHERE` clause, an index might hurt and not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE FACT_SALE FS
INNER JOIN DIM_PRODUCT DP ON FS.PRODUCT_NAME = DP.NAME
SET FS.PRODUCT_KEY = DP.ID
```

First of all,replace join with **`INNER JOIN`**.

Second thing you have to create index on column which you are using **`ON`** clause in **`JOIN`** condition.

Comment: `JOIN` would default to `INNER JOIN` here in MySQL.  Also, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769941/do-mysql-update-queries-benefit-from-an-index) an index on a join column could hurt the update rather than help it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes i got your point. There is one line **An index on the where column will speed up updates, and selects, but slow down some insertions.**